# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: only on VS CODE. WHY?

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

Im wondering why my code **works perfectly** on https://www.onlinegdb.com/online_java_compiler but on Visual Studio Code there seems to be an **error**:

**Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'int GenericTree.height()'
at SimpleTree02.main(SimpleTree02.java:7)**

I don't understand why there is no error on the site although I have checked and double-checked and it seems there are no errors. I copied the code from a youtube video so it should be 100% working, although this still has this error. I hope someone can help me, I am literally going crazy. Thanks in advance!

**Here is the code:**

```
import java.util.*;
                                            // Height of a Generic Trees
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        GenericTree tree = new GenericTree();
        // tree.display();
        int h = tree.height();
        System.out.println(h);
    }
}

class GenericTree {
    class Node {
        int data;
        ArrayList <Node> children;
        
        Node(int data) {
            this.data = data;
            children = new ArrayList <> ();
        }
    }
    
    private Node root;
    
    GenericTree() {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        this.root = ConstructorGT(s, null, 0);
    }
    
    private Node ConstructorGT(Scanner s, Node parent, int i) {
        if(parent == null) {
            System.out.println("Enter the data for the root node...");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Enter the data for the "+ i +"th child of the "+parent.data);
        }
        int data = s.nextInt();
        Node node = new Node(data);
        
        System.out.println("Enter the number of children of "+node.data);
        int n = s.nextInt();

        for(int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            Node child = ConstructorGT(s, node, j);
            node.children.add(child);
        }

        return node;
    }

    public void display() {
        display(this.root);
    }

    private void display(Node node) {
        String str = node.data + " => ";

        for(Node child: node.children) {
            str += child.data + ", ";
        }

        System.out.println(str);

        for(Node child: node.children) {
            display(child);
        }
    }

    public int height() {
        return this.height(root);
    }

    private int height(Node node) {
        int th = 0;

        for(Node child: node.children) {
            int ch = height(child);
            if(ch > th) 
                th = ch;
        }
        return th+1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you make sure it actually recompiled your code? Maybe delete the out folder. Or better yet, use a real IDE.

Comment: *"I copied the code from a youtube video so it should be 100% working ..."* - There are at least three flaws in that logic.  :-)

Comment: The code can be run successfully in my VS Code. Check from the following ways: 1. The java file should be `Main.java`. 2 `Java: Clean Java Language Server Workspace` from command palette in VS Code. See if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

The only way that you can get that error is if the API that you compiled against is different from the API that you are running against.  Specifically the `SimpleTree02.java` source was compiled against a version of `GenericTree` that has the `height()` method.  But the version that you are running it against does not have that method.  (That's what the exception says!)

This suggests that you have a problem in the way that you are using the tools.  Maybe you didn't recompile `GenericTree`.  Maybe you did ... but you have set up the runtime classpath incorrectly so that the old version is still being used at runtime; i.e. when you are running the code.

A lot of the details are missing from your question, so I can't work out what exactly you did wrong and therefore what you need you fix.  However, my first paragraph should tell you what to look for.

Comment: I sent all the code, can you check if the error is there? the file is named as the public method,

Comment: The problem is not in the code.  But I note that the code in your question is for the `Main` class, but the exception message says `SimpleTree02`.  So the exception does not match the code you showed us.